# Класс как массив

Tags: objective-c, xcode

При запуске `ViewController` инициализируеться переменная другого класса как массив:

```
@implementation ViewController {

   MYClass *_class[4][4]; 

}
```

И получаеться что переменная `_class` хранит в себе массив объектов `MYClass` и при этом к ним можно обращаться как `_class[2][2].value` где `value` это переменная класса `MYClass`.

Все отлично работает, но мне надо из другого класса получить доступ к этой `_class` - возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

объявить `_class` в @interface в .h а не в @implementation (фактически сделать его паблик вместо прайвет)

Comment: Это не получаешься сделать, выдает: "Property cannot have array or function type 'MYClass *[4][4]'"

Comment: Хотя если определить  `_class` вне @interface, то в принципе то что надо, но то что она полностью публичная конечно не очень хорошо.